# Nodejs, Add page number and custom header for merged pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, merge, puppeteer

I am generating pdf with the help of [puppeteer-cluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cluster) and [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) from different html pages in parallel then I use node library [pdf-merger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) for merging these files to single pdf. The problem is I need to have correct page number in the merged pdf. I could find puppeteer-report but I couldn't find any way to set start page for each part. Is there any library or tool in nodejs for solving this issue? For example a library for merging pdfs with support for setting contentious page number for final pdf file.

Comment: Library and tool requests are off-topic. Please share your code so far and if a library helps solve the problem, an answer will provde it. Thanks.